# Debug/Trace messages using ELMAH in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

How do we add debug/Trace messages using ELMAH in MVC application

Comment: Your question is too general. Um, read the documentation on the ELMAH site and follow it?

Answer (score 6):

ELMAH is usually used to report exceptions and not as a general Debug/Trace log.

For Debug/Trace logging I would suggest a combination of [log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98080/what-is-the-best-logging-solution-for-a-c-net-3-5-project) and [Log4PostSharp](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp).

Comment: I don't know... I already have ELMAH installed in my site and now I just want to tell ELMAH to also output those using Trace.TraceError.  I really need to add another logging framework for that?

Answer (score 5):

Elmah will catch unhandled exceptions automatically.

By tracing I think you mean logging exceptions that are handled?

If you want to manually log handled exceptions, the process in MVC is the same as for ASP.NET:

Add a reference to the Elmah DLL to your project, and then use `Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise()`, like this:

```
try
{
    throw new ApplicationException("raised for elmah to catch");
}
catch (System.ApplicationException ae)
{
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ae);
}
```