# ASP.NET Monitoring with Elmah

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, elmah

I want to use Elmah to monitor every activity made on my ASP.NET application.

I am not interested in logging only errors rather every activities made on my ASP.NET application, like:

1. How long need a user to submit a form (to check usability of my application)
2. Which action he takes to complete a task (click button 1 *@10:41* click button 2 *@10.51*)
3. Store this information in a database

The application is using C# and JavaScript.

Can I achieve this with Elmah or are there other options?

Comment: Not the same, but a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377997/debug-trace-messages-using-elmah-in-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it using ELMAH. In configuration you can set the logging destination to xml/db or email and easily change it. I have used for on esmall application. It is quick and useful.

Comment: @hemant: As far as i know, ELMAH can only log Exceptions: ELMAH stands for `Error Logging Modules and Handlers`